# Entity Framework Future Query with Single

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to use Future Queries with the .Single method?

eg: I want to get the one row marked as IsDefault then get its ID, but I want this batched up using Future Queries with another couple of calls.

```
Context.MyTable.Single(s => s.IsDefault).ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by doing a Where first with Future, then a .Single later to get the ID.

eg:

```
var f = Context.MyTable.Where(w => w.IsDefault).Future();
var ID = f.Single().ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FutureFirstOrDefault()` to get a single row.

```
Context.MyTable.Where(s => s.IsDefault)
               .Select(s => s.ID)
               .FutureFirstOrDefault();
```

If you wanted to ensure there was only one row that matches your query you could use `FutureCount()` as well.

These are both listed in the documentation at: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries